# How to get opacity value of CaptionStyle (Android 19-Kitkat)?

Tags: android, closed-captions

I'm working on a application where I use the API 19 (KitKat) and the Closed Caption feature. For the moment, I can access the data about the setting of the CC(example: background color ), but there are some values that I can not get, specifically: Background  opacity’.

Android returns an object called CaptionStyle, but I do not know how to get the opacity of this object. I have read the documentation related this class, but I found nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Get the forward/background color, and use it to determine the color:

```
captionStyle.backgroundColor /0xff000000; //Opacity of background
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. :) But, I don't know how to get the opacity of the background. Could you give me an example, please ?

Comment: I did... Basically, divide by the number included, and the opacity should be what's left.